# getRuntime().exec(String[]) function behaves differently to getRuntime().exec(String) (Android)

Tags: java, android, exec

Was trying to call ping with some custom data (`-p` flag). Since I needed to pass parameters, it seemed intuitive to use the `exec()` overload that accepts an array of strings. It kept failing so I tried the same exact input as one long string and now everything is fine. I have no idea what the problem is, I have checked the input multiple times.

Tried messing with additional spaces inside the array of strings to rule out any problems with missing spaces between parameters.

```
String sPattern = StringUtils.bytesToHex(sData.getBytes());
sPattern = padHexString(sPattern);
sPattern = "-p " + sPattern.toLowerCase(); // "-p 3132372e302e302e31ffffffffffffff"

// this FAILS
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/system/bin/ping",
                   "-c 1",
                    "-s 64",
                    sPattern,
                    sReportServer});  


// this WORKS
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 -s 64 " + 
                          sPattern + " " + sReportServer);
```

The first call fails and either shows me the usage, or gives an error that the "pattern must be hex digits." which it is. The second call works fine.

Both methods should work fine.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger You're right, not sure why I figured each switch and associated parameter should be together. That solved the problem. Any idea how the underlying mechanism treats spaces inside the arguments?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger it's an Android Phone (9.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Carlos Heuberger pointed out, I had spaces inside some of the arguments, and this was causing the call to fail. My thought was to pair the switch and associated parameter in the same string but this causes it to be wrapped by double quotes.

Hopefully this can save some time for someone who does the same thing :|